# How to use Node.Js twit (Github) for direct message Twitter API

Tags: node.js, twitter

I use Twit for testing the API of Twitter and see the usage here: https://github.com/ttezel/twit

I wanted to know if it's possible to do direct message with Twit, cause nothing to speak about in the usage.

Comment: I have the same problem, because It worked but it isn't working now, is it caused by the premium api?

Comment: It's seems like no, that's weird.